# ASCII.GetBytes in a switch statement error - Unable to cast object type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have the following C# code-

```
switch (Convert.ToInt32(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(grdGrading.Text.Trim())))
```

`grdGrading` is a Data grid.

I am currently getting this error - `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.`

Any ideas on what is causing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Convert.ToInt32()` doesn't work with arrays of bytes.  It's assuming that you're passing it an `object` that implements `IConvertible`.  Use `BitConverter.ToInt32()` instead.

As noted by @AVD, however, it looks like what you really want to use is `Int32.TryParse()`.

Answer (score 1):

If `grdGrading.Text` property return `digits (numeric value)` then use `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse` method to parse string data.

```
int value;

if(int.TryParse(grdGrading.Text.Trim(),out value))
{
  //code
}
```